# How to print keys and values in Array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to format my array into something like this: `name is John, age is 30`. Here is my sample array and code:

```
$user = array(
    'name' => 'John',
    'age' => 35
);

echo key($user)." is ".($user[key($user)]).","; // prints "name is John,"
```

The comma `(,)` will be gone if there's no more results to be printed out.

I am bad at logic but can you help me for this? It will be a great help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you really need an implode for just 2 array keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$values =[];

foreach ($user as $key => $value) {
    $values[] = "{$key} is {$value}";
}
echo implode(', ', $values);
```

Or

```
$values = array_map(fn($key, $value) => "{$key} is {$value}", array_keys($user), $user);
echo implode(', ', $values);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$user = array(
    'name' => 'John',
    'age' => 35
);

// echo key($user)." is ".($user[key($user)]).",";

$counter = count($user);
$i = 1;
$res = '';

foreach ($user as $key => $value) {
    $res .= $key. " is ". $value;
    if ($counter != $i) {
       $res = $res .", ";
    }
    $i = $i + 1;
}
echo $res;
```